# How do I load all the videos at once in a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-channel

[image]How do I load all the videos at once in a YouTube channel?

For example consider this photo if we click on load more only some videos of the channel are loaded

My doubt is how to load all the videos of the channel at once instead of clicking load more again and again.

Comment: no I am asking in a youtube channel for example this [link](https://www.youtube.com/user/marquesbrownlee/videos)

Comment: I think we're going to need some more details. What, exactly, is the problem you're trying to solve? What's not working for you the way things are now? Please [edit] your question.